# Check if DSN exist in excel vba

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I have a excel workbook connected to a MySQL server. I placed a refresh button that refresh the data and it holds unprotect and protect statements for the sheet.

My problem is when open the excel file and click on refresh in a computer that is not in the network, I get a get a DSN creating wizard and also If I press cancel in the wizard the sheet becomes unprotected.

I want to place a IF condition that checks if the DSN is available and if not it should exit sub.

Any ideas?

This is my code with error handler, but I still get the DSN creation wizard and after the msgbox is closed the sheet is unprotected

```
On Error GoTo handler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("DEC-2015").Unprotect Password:="password"
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query from Sample").Refresh
Sheets("DEC-2015").Protect _
Password:="password", _
UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
AllowFiltering:=True, _
AllowSorting:=True, _
AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
handler:
MsgBox "Server Connection Lost...", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Warning"
Exit Sub
```

Comment: Just a stab, try turning alerts off with `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`.

Comment: That did the trick, but it still unprotected my sheet (which is my biggest concern :()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn alerts off by altering your code to the following:

```
Public Sub DoSomething()

    On Error GoTo handler

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook
        .Sheets("DEC-2015").Unprotect Password:="password"
        .Connections("Query from Sample").Refresh
        .Sheets("DEC-2015").Protect _
            Password:="password", _
            UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
            AllowFiltering:=True, _
            AllowSorting:=True, _
            AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

    Exit Sub

    handler:
        ThisWorkbookSheets("DEC-2015").Protect _
            Password:="password", _
            UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
            AllowFiltering:=True, _
            AllowSorting:=True, _
            AllowUsingPivotTables:=True

        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .DisplayAlerts = True
        End With

        MsgBox "Server Connection Lost...", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Warning"

End Sub
```